# How do I track which domains/IPs OpenVPN users visit?

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

I have a small VPN service I run for myself and a few friends and I would like to start logging which domains/IPs a client visits.  I can retrieve all of the domains visited by the VPS I host this on using Wireshark, but this doesn't link to the client usernames within OpenVPN.

I've also tried setting `verb` and `log-append` to my `server.conf`, but that either results in the raw packet data (which I can see no easy way to decode) or not enough information to detect where they're going.

Am I missing a simple way with the logging?  Or is there another way to track where the users are going and link them up.

Answer (score 2):

We do it this way:

```
learn-address         /opt/openvpn/scripts/openVPN-learnAddress.pl
```

and that script /opt/openvpn/scripts/openVPN-learnAddress.pl
is used to apply firewalling rules. In our case we use this to block access except to permitted destination, but you could simply add a logging rule.